# Accessing Google IAP OAuth 2.0 protected website using C# .NET - error getting tokens in OAuth Playground

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, oauth2-playground

One of the websites we used to get data from requires now log in via Google, I have been granted access, and want to update the app to continue working.

I've set up credentials (clientId, clientSecret) as well as service account - whichever is easier tbh.

The url I'm trying to access looks like "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/view/company_name"

When logging in manually, I'm being informed that:

> To continue, Google will share your name, email address, language preference and profile picture with iap.googleapis.com.

Trying to get it working first on:
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

But each time I select scope (guessing here) Google OAuth2 API v2 (userinfo.email, userinfo.profile) and get the tokens I end up receiving following error message:

> Invalid IAP credentials: Expected JWT to have 3 parts separated by a '.' but there are 2 parts

Could anyone tell me all the things I'm doing wrong here?